# Spring data aerospike

Tags: java, spring-data, aerospike

I would like to work with `Aerospike` and use `Spring Data`. I found useful library for my goals [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-aerospike).

However, but adding it to dependencies, this code from sample still could not find dependencies.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAerospikeRepositories(basePackageClasses = 
ContactRepository.class)
class ApplicationConfig extends AbstractAerospikeConfiguration {
public @Bean(destroyMethod = "close") AerospikeClient aerospikeClient() {

    ClientPolicy policy = new ClientPolicy();
    policy.failIfNotConnected = true;

    return new AerospikeClient(policy, "localhost", 3000);
}

public @Bean AerospikeTemplate aerospikeTemplate() {
    return new AerospikeTemplate(aerospikeClient(), "bar");
}
}
```

Even less information could be find in the google. I've already tried to add another repos, like:

```
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Also, you could find example of project [here](https://github.com/carosys/spring-boot-web-aerospike-application/tree/master/aerospike-spring-boot). And guess what? That also won't be built.

I've installed latest `Maven`, updated repositories, still no result. Maybe I am missing some core dependencies?

> EDIT:

I've added just like any other dependency. Firstly, It wasn't found at all, but after updating `Maven` that looked OK. However, I still couldn't import needed sources.

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-aerospike</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: How did you add that `spring-data-aerospike` dependency? Could you show the related pom.xml snippet?

Comment: @romanpuchkovskiy, I've updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty strange, but:

1. It is not in the central: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cspring-data-aerospike
2. It is not in spring's libs-release: https://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/data/
3. There IS a snapshot in libs-snapshot: https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/data/spring-data-aerospike/
4. Here http://www.aerospike.jp/docs/connectors/spring/tutorial_1.html the tutorial depends on `spring-boot-starter-data-aerospike` which has version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, and `spring-boot-starter-data-aerospike` is not in the plugins-release repository: https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/springframework/boot/
5. In their master `pom.xml` https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-aerospike/blob/master/pom.xml the version is `1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` which is not `1.5.0.RELEASE` and which preceeds it
6. There are no tags and no releases in their github repository.

So it looks like no public release was ever made, and their recommendation to 'Add the Maven dependency' (the one that you added, with version `1.5.0.RELEASE`) will just not work.

To use this library in your project, you could make a checkout via git, build the project (`mvn install`), then use it from your local repository. Sources could be attached to your IDE manually. To build on other machines later, you could distribute the jar you built and use `mvn deploy:deploy-file` to install it to their local repositories.

Comment: also, you should run it like "mvn install -DskipTests"

Answer (score 3):

The Spring Data for Aerospike connector has been released using the com.aerospike group id and you can now download it from maven central.

A new [example project](https://github.com/aerospike/spring-boot-example) has been created which uses Spring Data for Aerospike.

The [tutorial](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/connectors/spring/tutorial_1.html) has also been updated to match the example project.

Answer (score 1):

These answers, including the accepted one are out of date. There have been many new developments in [Spring Data Aerospike](https://github.com/aerospike-community/spring-data-aerospike) and the auto-configuration project [aerospike-community/spring-boot-data-aerospike](https://github.com/aerospike-community/spring-boot-data-aerospike).

There is a [modern example of Spring Boot using Aerospike](https://github.com/aerospike-examples/simple-springboot-aerospike-demo) and an associated February 2021 blog post [Simple Web Application Using Java, Spring Boot, Aerospike and Docker](https://medium.com/aerospike-developer-blog/simple-web-application-using-java-spring-boot-aerospike-database-and-docker-ad13795e0089?source=friends_link&sk=43d747f5f55e527248125eeb18748d92). JARs are in [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=spring-data-aerospike).

Other relatively recent blog posts are

- [How to setup `spring-data-aerospike` in Spring Boot application](https://medium.com/aerospike-developer-blog/how-to-setup-spring-data-aerospike-in-spring-boot-application-afa8bcb59224?source=friends_link&sk=e16a3b69c814bfb22f200634c743e476)
- [Basic error handling in spring-data-aerospike](https://medium.com/aerospike-developer-blog/basic-error-handling-in-spring-data-aerospike-5edd580d77d9?source=friends_link&sk=cff71ea1539b36e5a89b2c3411b58a06)